# Creating hashMap in java

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. I am trying to create a hashMap and call hashMap class from another class. I have the following code below. i keep getting an error

```
package domain;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AumentumDocTypeMap {
  private HashMap<String, String> DocTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  DocTypeMap.put("7000690", "691");

  public HashMap<String, String> getTypeMap() {
       return DocTypeMap;
  }
}
```

I keep getting an error on DocTypeMap.put("7000690", "691"); saying syntaz errors on token, delete the tokens

Comment: Note that the convention is to start variable names with lower case letters, so `docTypeMap`.

Comment: You can't `put` at class level. Assuming you want to execute it when you create instance of `AumentumDocTypeMap ` you need to place it in constructor or initialization block.

Comment: Wouldn't really call it a duplicate in this introductory case because you'd have to know the error in order to google that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `put` call within a method, not the class body.

Add a constructor (gets called when your object is created) to initialize the class properly.

```
package domain;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AumentumDocTypeMap {
  private Map<String, String> docTypeMap;

  public AumentumDocTypeMap() {
      docTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      docTypeMap.put("7000690", "691");
  }

  public HashMap<String, String> getTypeMap() {
       return docTypeMap;
  }
}
```

Also, lower case first letters in variable names are standard :).  Though having upper case first letters won't actually break anything.

Also notice that I moved the hash map creation inside of the constructor.  Generally you should avoid initializing objects where you're declaring them and do it in the constructor (or static initializer block - you can google that) instead.

Also again - as pointed out in the comments by @Maxim, you should make the type of the map variable `Map<String, String>` as it allows you to change the implementation from, say, a hash map to a linked hash map or tree map.

Comment: Think it's better to use `Map<String, String>` to define the `docTypeMap` field

Comment: Start of the answer is little unclear. It says to `put the "put" within a method call` but then it is placed in constructor (which is *not* method).

Comment: Good call on both fronts :). ammended.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put values in any method. If you want that value it initially then put that in constructor :

```
public class AumentumDocTypeMap {
    private HashMap<String, String> DocTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Constructor
    public AumentumDocTypeMap(){
        DocTypeMap.put("7000690","691");
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getTypeMap() {
        return DocTypeMap;
    }
}
```